# Ublock не блокирует скрипт с Вконтакте

Tags: вконтакте, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Ublock не блокирует скрипт по адресу https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js 
В моих фильтрах поставил на блокировку всего вк (`||vk.com^`).

К примеру если перейти https://vk.com/js/api/test.js - блокирует а **openapi.js** не хочет. Вопрос как заблокировать этот скрипт через ublock?

Comment: `||vk.com^$all`

Comment: И всё равно не блокирует